# Database of bicycle sharing systems

Tags: data-request, transportation, city, public-transport

I am looking for a database of [bicycle sharing systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle-sharing_system). It does not need to be real-time (even though that would be wonderful).

Each entry should ideally have the following:

- Name of the system (ex: Vélib')
- Official URL (ex: http://velib.paris.fr)
- Wikidata page if available (ex: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1120762)
- Number of bicycles (ex: 18200 bicycles)
- Whether it is OK to leave bicycles anywhere or not (ex: false)
- Number of stations, if applicable (ex: 1230 stations)
- Name of the city (or area) of coverage, if possible as a Wikidata identifier (ex: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q90)
- Price per use/day/month/year if applicable (ex: 0EUR/1.70EUR/NA/29EUR)

Optional but would be great:

- Area covered (geographical shape or list of stations coordinates)
- Average daily ridership (ex: 108090 rides)
- URL of the mobile apps for Android and iOS (ex: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paris.velib)
- Stars given to the mobile apps (ex: 2.9/5)
- URL to a picture of a bicycle on Commons (ex: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Service_bicyclette_hangzhou_zhongguo.jpg)
- URL to a logo of the system (ex: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/66/V%C3%A9lib%E2%80%99_logo.svg/1280px-V%C3%A9lib%E2%80%99_logo.svg.png)

Answer (score 3):

One possible source is [citybik.es](https://citybik.es/), which does much more than collecting metadata about bicycle sharing systems: it also collects live info about the number of bikes in each docking station!

They have [an API](https://api.citybik.es/v2/) that can be used to list the providers that they support. For instance, the endpoint `https://api.citybik.es/v2/networks` will give you a JSON list of the bike sharing system that they support. Here is the metadata they have for Velib:

```
{
    "company": ["JCDecaux"],
    "href": "/v2/networks/velib",
    "id": "velib",
    "license": {
        "name": "Open Licence",
        "url": "https://developer.jcdecaux.com/#/opendata/licence"
    },
    "location": {
        "city": "Paris",
        "country": "FR",
        "latitude": 48.856614,
        "longitude": 2.3522219
     },
     "name": "Velib"
}
```

That is quite minimal, but it could be a starting point.